# How to comma-separate numbers in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, number-formatting

I have an EditText that has an inputType of *number*. While the user is typing, I want to comma-separate the numbers. Here's a little illustration:

> 123 would be represented as 123
>
> 1234 would be represented as 1,234
>
> 12345 would be represented as 12,345
>
> ...and so on.

I tried adding a comma with TextWatcher as shown below:

```
    EditText edittext = findViewById(R.id.cashGiven);

    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            editText.setText(separateWithComma(editText.getText().toString().trim()));
        }
    });
```

Pasting the `separateWithComma()` method here would make this question extra lengthy but then, it works: I tested it on Eclipse. I think the addTextChangedListener does not work this way because my app freezes (and then crashes much later) when I do this.

Is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks in anticipation for a positive response.

Comment: The problem with setting the text  in afterTextChanged is that it creates an infinite loop check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385081/how-can-i-change-the-edittext-text-without-triggering-the-text-watcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `String.format` instead of what you have now.
 **Replace this:**

```
editText.setText(separateWithComma(editText.getText().toString().trim()));
```

**with this:**

```
editText.setText(String.format("%,d", your number));
```

Another thing - your app may be getting this crash because every time that you are calling `setText()` inside `afterTextChanged`, another `afterTextChanged` is called and basically will create an infinite loop. If that is your problem you can find a good solution [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873652/application-get-freeze-whete-set-double-value-to-edit-text-using-typewriter-for).

Comment: Same outcome, the app started freezing like crazy. I don't think I should be using an addTextChangedListener. I think that's the problem.

Comment: @TaslimOseni In order to prevent the app from freezing, you should disable your textChangedListener when you are doing `setText("")` and enabled it again afterward.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                try {
                    String givenstring = s.toString();
                    Long longval;
                    if (givenstring.contains(",")) {
                        givenstring = givenstring.replaceAll(",", "");
                    }
                    longval = Long.parseLong(givenstring);
                    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
                    String formattedString = formatter.format(longval);
                    et.setText(formattedString);
                    et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
                    // to place the cursor at the end of text
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    nfe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                et.addTextChangedListener(this);

            }
        });
```

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54686264/8770663)

Comment: I want to display a comma separated string in EditText but if we fetch this value then it should return without comma

Answer (score 2):

**I've gotten two good answers but I just wanted to add this:**

The reason I was facing this problem was because `editText.setText(...)` was being called recursively inside the `afterTextChanged()` function of my TextWatcher. As the previous answerers rightly stated, the solution is to **temporarily stop the`afterTextChanged()` method from firing** this way:

```
private boolean edit = true;
private int cursorPosition;

...
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    cursorPosition = editText.getText().toString().length() - editText.getSelectionStart();
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable){
    if(edit){
        edit = false;
        editText.setText(String.format("%,d", Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString().trim())));
        edit = true;
    }
    //setting the cursor back to where it was          
    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length() - cursorPosition);
}
```

This way, we have carefully meandered our way. But this poses a NEW PROBLEM:

Using this strategy, we assume that the string within the EditText can easily be translated into an `int`. As we input more numbers, the app would definitely crash with a NumberFormatException because of the commas. Therefore, it is important we find a way to solve this problem. Here's a method I wrote to help me:

```
public String getCommalessNumber(String commaNumber){

    String newNumber = "";
    String[] split = commaNumber.trim().split(",");

        for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
            newNumber += split[i];
         }

    return newNumber;
}
```

Finally, we can do this:

```
boolean edit = true;

...
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable){
        if(edit){
            edit = false;
            editText.setText(String.format("%,d", Integer.parseInt(getCommalessNumber(editText.getText().toString().trim()))));
            edit = true;
         }
    }
```

I hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

For those that might want to use this approach, change the return type of getCommalessNumber(String commaNumber) method to String instead of int.

Answer (score 0):

use this method for separate by 3

```
public static String intSeparatorBy3(String number) {

    String reversed = reverse_string(number);

    StringBuilder separated = new StringBuilder();
    if (number.length() <= 3) {
        separated = new StringBuilder(number);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < reversed.length(); i++) {

            // when i is the third part of number
            if (i != 0 && i % 3 == 0) separated.append(",");

            separated.append(reversed.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return reverse_string(separated.toString());
}
```